# Best way to run data script on heroku console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, activerecord, console

I am trying to move postgresql data from a json column to a different column within the same table.

How can I do this efficiently? My heroku console dies after 10-20 minutes and I have 100,000+ records to update.

```
Ticket.where(payment_type: nil).find_each(batch_size: 1000) do |ticket|
   ticket.update_attributes(payment_type: ticket.data['_embedded']['payments'][0]['_embedded']['name']) if ticket.data['_embedded']['payments'].present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting it to a rake task and then use:

```
heroku run:detached rake <yourtaskname>
```

John.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#running-tasks-in-background

Comment: Do you know why convert it should be converted to a rake task?